# retrieve data from mongodb to angular

Tags: html, arrays, angular, mongodb

I am trying to get all the data from mongodb but it shows `[object] [object]` how do I get array data to angular from mongodb?
Here is my code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";

import {Model} from "../model/model";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-take-quiz',
  templateUrl: './take-quiz.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./take-quiz.component.css']
})
export class TakeQuizComponent implements OnInit {
  data:Model[]=[];

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.quizAll();
  }

  quizAll(){
    this.http.get<any>('https://localhost:8080/quizzes/').subscribe(response=>
    {
      console.log(response);
      // @ts-ignore
      this.data=response;

     });

  }
}
```

model.ts

```
export interface Model {
  title:string;
  description:string;
}
```

html

```
<div>
  <p>your data {{data}}</p>
</div>
```

Here is the screenshot of console [image: snapshot of console]

when I try

```
<div>
      <p>your data {{data.title}}</p>
</div>
```

It shows following error
[image: error image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [JSON Pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe) in order to display the whole data as string . Detailed explanation in https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-json-pipe-example and data used in the html is an array not an object. In order to show all title loop through data as given below

```html
<span *ngFor="let val of data">{{val.title}}</span>
```

Comment: I went through the documentation but I'm not able to get the exact value it always throws object when I try to get value from html file.